# The number of solutions of the equation $1 + \sin x\sin^2 {\frac{x}{2}} =0$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$ is...

Tags: trigonometry

> The number of solutions of the equation $1 + \sin x\sin^2 {\frac{x}{2}} =0$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$ is...

What I have tried...

Since, $\sin \frac{x}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}}$,
$$ 1 + \sin x\cdot\frac{1-\cos x}{2} = 0$$
$$2+\sin x \cdot (1-\cos x) = 0$$
From here onwards I am not sure how to continue...

*P.S. The answer to this question is $0$* ( which means that the equation has no solution. Please explain how) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.  Don't try to solve the equation algebraicly.  Instead, the product of your sine terms has to be $-1$.  What are the possible outputs of sin?  How can you get that product to be $-1$?